# Printing disfigures page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I have a PHP file which pulls information from database and the previous pages. It looks something like this:

[image: PHP file]

Whenever I try to print the page it prints out as this:

[image: Print preview]

At first I thought I could fix this using media queries, but I was wrong. Media queries didn't help me a bit.

**My Question**

How can I print the page (in Portrait view, preferably in an A4 page) without it being disfigured.

Thanks

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with PHP ! It's styling, you really should change the tags ! You may also past the codes here, so I can check your styling

Comment: @Soheyl Okay, done

Comment: When you said queries, did you mean you used **@media print**  queries?

Comment: @Laiman I meant the screen media queries in CSS. Such as [at]media only screen and (max-width: 600px). Will [at]media print solve my problem?

Comment: Yes try that, It might help you.

Comment: @Laiman Okay I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Laiman I've tried your solution and it worked!!! Thanks :)

Comment: @DigitalRevenge Alright, you welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a print media query (@media print), as suggested by [@Laiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612132/laiman) solved the problem.

Now after print it looks like this:

[image]